# Control+t - Selenium WebDriver y Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, chrome

Estoy probando la librería Selenium::WebDriver en Ruby e intentando abrir un navegador, cargar Google.com y abrir una nueva pestaña, pero no consigo que funcione, el código en cuestión:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome)

driver.navigate.to("https://www.google.com")

element = driver.find_element(:tag_name,'body')
puts("Elemento encontrado") if driver.find_element(:tag_name,'body')
element.send_keys(:command, 't')

sleep(5)
```

La versión de Ruby es 2.6.5

La versión de Selenium-WebDriver es 3.142.6

Tengo instalado el controlador de Chrome

El Script abre Chrome, carga google.com e imprime por pantalla "Elemento encontrado" pero no aplica "Control+t" y abre una nueva pestaña.

Comment: Pero estás haciendo `(:command, 't')`, no `(:control, 't')`

Comment: Porque lo hago en un Mac, tampoco funciona con :control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como alternativa a `CTRL+t` puedes usar lo siguiente para abrir una pestaña:

```rb
# Abrir una nueva pestaña
driver.execute_script('window.open()')

# Mover el contexto a la nueva pestaña para poder trabajar con ella
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```

Comment: Sí, fue la opción que usé cuando me rendí con las opciones de Control+T, Command+T, etc.